# stripslashes issue when character after two backslashes

Tags: php, stripslashes

I know it's stupid question, but I cannot to google anything for my problem.

I have `$q = "This is\\same text";` and do

```
$q = stripslashes($q);
```

So, `$q` is now equal to `"This issame text"`! How I can to save one backslash?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script does, what it's told, actually.

In `$q`, the double backslash evaluates to a single backslash (the first escapes the second backslash), which is then stripped away.

If meta-characters are not to be evaluated, you'll need to use single quotes:

```
$q = 'This is \\some text';
// String is now: This is \\some text

$q = stripslashes($q);
// String is now: This is \some text
```

---

**EDIT** <strike>According to your comment in Michaels answer</strike> there may be some confusion as to how many *valid* backslashes there are in your input. Consider the following input:

```
$q1 = "This is\\\some \text";
$q2 = 'This is\\\some \text';
```

The first would *actually* contain `This is \\some <TAB>ext`. This is due to PHP leaving invalid control characters as-is. `\s`, as opposed to `\t` is an invalid control character and is thus left in place.

The second string, however, would literally contain what's in the single quotes, since no evaluation is applied.

Comment: Oh, I understand it... Thanks. But if I have input string like this: $q = 'This is\same text', how can I to addslashes (4 times) to stripslashes next time?

Comment: Sorry, your example is invalid, you add space after "is" in it. Try to write $q='This is\\some text' and you get same effect as in double quotes.

Comment: The spaces are irrelevant. The *relevant* part is that two backslashes in a double-quoted string evaluate to *one* backslash, whereas one backslash in a single-quoted string *remains* one backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Actually

```
$q = "This is\\same text";
```

contains one backslash.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that one backslash should stay there, double him

```
$q = "This is\same \\ text";

$q = stripslashes($q);
```

become

```
This issame \ text
```